# Does an app that made with ios sdk 4 install on device with os 4.2?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios4

Does an app that made with ios sdk 4 install on device with os 4.2 ?

I made an app with ios sdk 4.0.1 but now i want to install it from xcode on ipod touch with os 4.2 but says `No provisioned iPhone OS device is connected.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can run Applications for previous versions of iOS on a device with iOS 4.2.

The other way around might not be true: you may not be able to run applications compiled specifically for iOS 4.2 on devices with previous versions of iOS.

Keep in mind that with iOS 4.2 SDK you **CAN** create applications for devices running lower version of iOS also. It depends on how you configure your project on **info.plist** and the APIs you use in your application.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. There *might* be few cases of incompatibility, but they are very rare.

Edit: And in most cases, apps build against 4.2 will run on 4.0 just fine, if they use the new stuff wisely.

Answer (score 0):

In almost all circumstances your app should run. It's very unlikely for it to produce any errors.